# Ordering status modify after customer comes back from paypal.

Tags: php, magento, paypal

In Magento 1.7.0.2. the paypal is at standard payment if I go back to the webshop then order status is "processed". I want to modify to "paid" status. I tried this solution in Ipn.php file in the function "processIpnRequest", but it doesn't work.

```
{ 
  $orderIncrementId = $this->_getOrder->getIncrementId();
  $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
  $order->setStatus('fizetve');
  $order->save(); 
}
```

Has anybody idea about to modify the order's status when customer comes back from paypal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default order status to whatever you want, but for this you need to create a small module so that you can define what order status you need.

Following link provide an example.

http://www.jimcode.org/2011/08/setting-orders-complete-or-status-magento/

If you are willing to change the core file as you tried above for ipn.php

use as follows :

```
$orderId = YOUR_ORDER_ID;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true)->save();

Similarly you can do :

$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true)->save();

&

$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true)->save();
```

Comment: My solution:

    We have to make new status at the admin interface at "Order statuses" item.   

    Clicking list:
    system -> Order statuses -> Assign Status to state

    At this page we have to assign the order's status to the new payment status.
    The original assignment has to be deleted by clicking at "Unassign" and it's working.

    Thanks for the help.